# I upgraded to FQL to Graph API - am I using it correctly?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I used the FQL until a few days ago to retrieve Facebook data, but I noticed that it will be discontinued in about 1 year so I upgraded to Graph API. But am I using it correctly? Will this method work still next year? I am still using a

`facebook.php`, 
`base_facebook.php` and 
`fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt`

from 2011 but then again I only need these functions.

Here's my code, thanks for any advice you can give me :)

```
        function get_content($URL){
                  $ch = curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
                  $data = curl_exec($ch);
                  curl_close($ch);
                  return $data;
        }

        $access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();

        $data = get_content("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $facebook_id . "/?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=".$access_token);
        $data_array = json_decode($data, true);

        $new_array = array(
            "uid" => $data_array['id'],
            "name" => $data_array['name'],
            "first_name" => $data_array['first_name'],
            "last_name" => $data_array['last_name'],
            "email" => $data_array['email']
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks perfectly correct!

The only improvement to that code would be to add the API version number to the call.

So, use `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/`

```
$data = get_content("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/**" . $facebook_id . "/?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=".$access_token);
```

That way, you'll not be affected by any changes until at least July 2017!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to catch any connection or HTTP errors returned.
Some of the HTTP errors are documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4).

You can use the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) for making test API calls and verifying your requests.